# How to fix org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnsupportedZipFeatureException(epub mimetype)?

Tags: java, exception, zip

My jboss shows the error while zip file is being on unzip process.

Error message

```
14:36:20,663 ERROR [STDERR] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnsupportedZipFeatureException: unsupported feature data descriptor used in entry mimetype
14:36:20,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.read(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:245)
14:36:20,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

here's a part of entrys of test.epub

```
Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
  20  Stored       20   0% 03-18-2013 14:39 2cab616f  mimetype
   0  Stored        0   0% 03-18-2013 10:42 00000000  META-INF/
 265  Defl:N      187  29% 03-18-2013 10:42 4d7842ce  META-INF/container.xml
1048  Defl:N      271  74% 03-18-2013 10:42 c04d123d  META-INF/encryption.xml
   0  Stored        0   0% 03-18-2013 12:05 00000000  OEBPS/
1014  Defl:N      530  48% 03-18-2013 12:05 cb8218d1  OEBPS/9.html
```

LIB : commons-compress-1.4.jar
1.5 version has showed the same error msg.

Anybody know why the error occurred and how I fix it??

Add the code

```
public void unzip(InputStream is, File destDir, String charsetName)
        throws IOException {
    ZipArchiveInputStream zis;
    ZipArchiveEntry entry;
    String name;
    File target;
    int nWritten = 0;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];
    zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(is, charsetName, false);
    while ((entry = zis.getNextZipEntry()) != null) {
        name = entry.getName();
        target = new File(destDir, name);
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            target.mkdirs();
        } else {
            Util.createParentDirectory(target);
            target.createNewFile();
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target));
            while ((nWritten = zis.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, nWritten);
            }
            bos.close();
            debug("file : " + name);
        }
    }
    zis.close();
}
```

When I use other LIB(Java.util.zip), also shows the Exception below.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: could you post the Java code?

Comment: I edited my question with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because you have what is called, "data descriptor" attached to this "mimetype" file. By default (and spec,) only DEFLATED files are allowed to have this, but you have it on STORED (uncompress file within the ZIP.)

Just construct your ZipArchiveInputStream with allowStoredEntriesWithDataDescriptor=true.

```
public ZipArchiveInputStream(InputStream inputStream,
                         String encoding,
                         boolean useUnicodeExtraFields,
                         boolean allowStoredEntriesWithDataDescriptor)
```

Comment: Nice answer! I've the same problem but with "java.util.zip.ZipInputStream". Is there a way to specify something like "allowStoredEntriesWithDataDescriptor" in my case? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem possible with java.util.zip: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.java#L310

Comment: eight years later, but is there a good reason that `allowStoredEntriesWithDataDescriptor` is `false` by default?  Is it a security risk?

Comment: @Black see: https://github.com/apache/commons-compress/pull/137#issuecomment-690835644